# How bootstrap V4 is displaying a caret with this style?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

This Bootstrap dropdown style mentioned [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/0ffd369afdfa064b3a56078ac4351aae01a8c6cf/scss/_dropdown.scss) displays a caret next to the dropdown as in these [examples](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/).

How can this style display a caret? I don't see any reference to the image or special characters.

Comment: It's done with [Pseudo Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements): line 9 [::after](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/0ffd369afdfa064b3a56078ac4351aae01a8c6cf/scss/_dropdown.scss)

Comment: How that line 9 displaying the carrot? I don't see any img or special character in that style for the pseudo element ::after.

Comment: There is no image or special character, it's just CSS. The borders are creating the "carrot".

Comment: wow! How that borders are creating a triangle is surprising me!

Comment: A "carrot" is an orange-colored (or, in the wild, ranging from purple to yellow) vegetable . The word you seem to be looking for is ["caret"](https://superuser.com/questions/548862/is-there-a-text-caret-unicode-character).

Answer (score 0):

I found an [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/5rcL6/) about creating arrows with CSS.

`.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; /* 40px height (20+20) */
    border-left: 20px solid green;
    position:absolute;
}`